# javafx, alpha channel not working on window title

Tags: png, javafx-2, alpha-transparency

I have a little image with alpha channel that, when rendered on the window title bar, presents a sort of "frame" effect. 
[image: Framed icon]

It is not a problem of the image, because using swing i get it rendered correctly:

[image]

The code for the first case is:

```
    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(bp));
    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png"));
    primaryStage.getIcons().add(image);
```

The working example has been generated with good old swing:

```
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
    setIconImage(ii.getImage());
```

My idea is that i missed some advanced javafx Image setting, but i've no clue on what is this missing setting.

Follows the png image:
[image: image.png]

OS:win 7, JavaFX 2.1

Comment: Looks like a rendering glitch to me.  I think you should file an issue at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com to get the JavaFX developers to investigate it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you've met a bug. I've filed it as http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23859

Feel free to add your comments or votes to that bug.